# cannot stack the divs on top of each other, img is right beside the other elements

Tags: html, css, position

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

div.div1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  float: left;
}

div.div2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: green;
  color: black;
  float: left;
}

div.div3 {
  margin-top: 350px;
  margin-left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
}

div.parent {
  margin-top: 200px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
}

p.one {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
}

p.two {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}

img.haus {
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

img.head {
  width: 90%;
  height: 800px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="vorbereitung.css" type="text/css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <section>
    <div class="div1">
      <p class="one">Willkommen</p>
      <p class="one">Jordan 1</p>
      <p class="one">Jordan 3</p>
      <p class="one">Jordan 4</p>
    </div>
    <div class="div2">
      <img class="haus" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/11/04/06/21/drawing-516251_960_720.png">
      <p class="two">Neue Modelle</p>
      <p class="two">Reduziert</p>
      <p class="two">Shop all</p>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
      <img class="head" src="https://www.kicksonfire.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/Air-Jordan-4-What-The-1-1.jpg?x27993">
      <div class="div3">Shop Jordan 4</div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

I have a problem with div `.parent`, image `img.head`, and div `.div3`. I want to stack img and div3 on top of each other and put them in `.parent` div. There is no error, but the img is outside of the div right next to the other elements. I've tried to position absolute and relative but its not working, please help.

Comment: HTML will not throw any error, please add desired result screen, so someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

```
img.head {
   width: 90%;
   height: 800px;
}

div.div3 {
   margin-top: 350px;
   position: absolute;
   background-color: white;
   top: 10px;
   left:10px;
}
```

(you can use top and left to keep the elements at the required place)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).